# HTMLAgilitypack remove <a> node

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am trying to remove a node using htmlagilitypack and have been unsuccessful.
Here's how the html looks like:
example1:

```
    <tr><td class="RL">Begindate:</td><td class="RL" colspan="3">12/1/2014<br/></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="QL">Company Name:</td><td class="QL" colspan="3">
                    Abd El & Jake Holdings, LLC<br/><span class="upd">in business since 12/1/2014</span><br/></td></tr>
    <tr></tr><tr><td class="RL">Address:</td><td class="RL" colspan="3">
                            North 10th   Street,&nbsp;18049
    <tr><td class="RL" colspan="3"><a onclick="showPopWin('showOnMap.html?
    address=North 10th street;city=Emmaus;country=&amp;
    compname=Consistoire%2bde%2bla%2bSynagogue', 680, 360, null); return false;" href="showOnMap.html?address=North 10th street&amp;
    city=Emmaus&amp;country=&amp;
    compname=Consistoire%2bde%2bla%2bSynagogue">
    <img title="img" alt="img" src="/kbopub/images/pin12.gif" class="edit"/></a></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="QL">Status:</td><td class="QL" colspan="3">InActive
                            <br/>

    example2: 
    <tr><td class="RL">Begindate:</td><td class="RL" colspan="3">1/1/2004<br/></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="QL">Company Name:</td><td class="QL" colspan="3">
                    ABC Company, LLC<br/><span class="upd">in business  since 1/1/2002</span><br/></td></tr>
    <tr></tr><tr><td class="RL">Address</td><td class="RL" colspan="3">                                 Central   Parkway,&nbsp;11902
   <tr><td class="RL" colspan="3"><<a onclick="showPopWin('showOnMap.html?
   address=Central%2bParkway%252C+11902&amp;
   city=FL+32224+Jacksonville%2bflorida&amp;
   country=America&amp;
   compname=Abd', 680, 360, null); return false;"
   href="showOnMap.html?    address=Central%2bParkway%252C+11902&amp;city=FL+32224+Jacksonville%2bflorida&amp;country=Am   erica&amp;compname=Abd">
   <img title="img" alt="img" src="/kbopub/images/pin12.gif" class="edit"/></a></td></tr>
     <tr><td class="QL">Status:</td><td class="QL" colspan="3">Active<br/>
```

I used

```
var QRnode = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='RL']");
```

But this shows the whole node. How can I remove all the elements in  tag?

Thanks
Rashmi

Answer (score 1):

With this you can remove each `tag` independently:

```
var documentNode = document.DocumentNode;
var RL = documentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='RL']");
RL.Remove();
```

For delete all you need to iterate over all the `tags` with you previous code.

Comment: note that this not remove the nodes in the server side.

Comment: Of course not, the server side HTMLis read-only for the user. This only works for you own downloaded HTML.